# firewalld to block ICMP traffic excypt from preassigned IPs

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld

I have been trying to convert a iptables settings to firewalld on a new server. The existing rule blocks ICMP except from a subset of IPs. Only people from our IT subnet (192.168.10.0/24) and our monitoring server (10.10.10.10) should be able to ping the server. In some cases additional servers would have additional IPs enabled to get a ping response.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p ICMP -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p ICMP -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p ICMP -s 10.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p ICMP -s N.N.N.N -j ACCEPT
```

Then when I try to apply similar rules, using firewalld rich rules, I am able to create a rule to allow either the IT subnet or the monitoring server, but not both. I appear to have the same problem as described in [this question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/877494/firewalld-how-to-whitelist-just-two-ip-addresses-not-on-the-same-subnet) I've seen several other pages with proposed solutions, but all have failed in one way or another. I've since reverted my test box back to defaults.

After I update this ICMP rule I will need to write a more restrictive SSH access lists, which allows a smaller subset of the IT range to access these machines. At this point adding the SSH rules in this process would have unexpected results.

```
rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.10.0/24" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source address="10.10.10.10" accept
    rule family="ipv4" source NOT address="192.168.10.0/24" drop
```

The results of these rules result with:

1. Blocking all traffic, not just ICMP
2. Without the "NOT address drop" line I can ping the server on devices I shouldn't be able to
3. With the "NOT address drop" line I can not ping from my monitoring server at 10.10.10.10
4. Adding the rules to iptables, using the commands above, does work but are deleted on a reboot

**UPDATE 1**
I've revisiting multi-Zone approach as recommended. The issue appears that my "ssh" people are being caught up with my ITsubnet zone. This is preventing them from SSH access.

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=ITsubnet --list-all
ITsubnet (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.10.0/24
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=MonitoringSRV --list-all
MonitoringSRV (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 10.10.10.10
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=SSH_Access --list-all
SSH_Access (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.10.10
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno16777984
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

PS found [this explainer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/understanding-firewalld-multi-zone-configurations) which helped.

Comment: Stop using rich rules, create zones instead.

Comment: I tried using a few zone approaches, but in those cases there was still things which weren't working correctly. If you have a specific guide or example I would be interested in trying again as I read several times that rich-rules should be avoided.

Comment: A zone is just a group of firewall rules applied to either a network interface, or a set of source addresses (which is what you want here). So, group together all the source addresses that will have the _same_ firewall rules, and make a zone with them. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: His iptables rules can't be correct. The `DROP` should be at the end. In that configuration, ALL the icmp packets are dropped at the first line without reaching next lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands used to make changes in **UPDATE 1**

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=ITsubnet
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=MonitoringSRV
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=SSH_access
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ITsubnet --add-source=192.168.10.0/24
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=MonitoringSRV --add-source=10.10.10.10
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=SSH_access --add-source=192.168.10.10
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=SSH_access --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --set-target=DROP
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Blocks all ssh access even from 192.168.10.10.

Commands used to make changes in **UPDATE 2**

Zone name appears to influence order so ITsubnet is processed before SSH_access. This is confirmed with:

```
iptables -S
```

or

```
iptables -vnL
```

So changing the zone name to get the more specific rule to process first fixes this issue.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --delete-zone=SSH_Access
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=A1_First010
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=A1_First010 --add-source=192.168.10.10
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=A1_First010 --add-service=ssh
```

Comment: You should not use `--permanent` in firewalld commands and then follow them up with `--reload`. This may cause it to be impossible to access your system if you make a mistake. You should instead leave off `--permanent` and use `--runtime-to-permanent` when the firewall rules are complete and correct.