# block ping 8.8.8.8 in firewalld

Tags: firewalld, firewalld-zone

Working from my Arch Console (having not yet installed Openbox), I've installed `firewalld`, `sudo pacman -S firewalld`, then, to check that it's overall working, `firewall-cmd --panic-on` correctly blocks my `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`. But is it specifically working for my LAN port `enp0s25`?  When I configure like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=drop --change-interface=enp0s25
firewall-cmd --zone=drop --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="8.8.8.8" reject'
```

(The last line [thanks to Hitesh Jethva](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/working-with-firewalld/).) I can still get a `ping` from `8.8.8.8`. Why, and is there a way from the Console to check that `firewalld` is working for my interface?

Comment: Block ICMP responses. That would realistically block all traffic from 8.8.8.8 which you wouldn't want. See this prior post: https://serverfault.com/questions/897297/firewalld-to-block-icmp-traffic-excypt-from-preassigned-ips

Comment: Also according to this prior post rich rules aren't even really that necessary: https://serverfault.com/questions/680780/block-all-but-a-few-ips-with-firewalld

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to block ping towards 8.8.8.8, so that is not source address, it's destination address. You could use [rich rules](https://www.ait.com/tech-corner/11486-advanced-firewalld-configuration-with-rich-rulesnbsp) to configure it if there are many IPs that change often.

Generally speaking, you can block ICMP like this:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-icmp-block={echo-request,echo-reply,timestamp-reply,timestamp-request} --permanent 

firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can also use pre-defined lists of IPs/objects. See [here](https://www.tecmint.com/firewalld-rules-for-centos-7/2/) how.

Comment: Nope, that `icmp-block` didn't stop the pings in for my interface in zone `drop`, and neither did setting `source address="138.201.81.199" reject` in my rich rule block `ping archlinux.org`...

Comment: Neither could I block `pacman -S wget`, nor  `wget https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wget`...